# R (ggplot2) : Understanding different behaviour when using shape or colour in aes( )

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a ggplot:

```
  ggplot(data.and.factors.prov,aes(x=Design.Complexity,y=FP,shape=factor(All.interactions))) + 
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal,position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) + 
    geom_blank() + 
    geom_smooth(method='lm',se=F,formula=y~x,colour='black')  + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(17,3,16,6,15,4),
                       name='Interactions',
                       labels=c('No interactions','All possible interactions','Randomly picked interactions\nand direct effects')) + 
    labs(x='Design.complexity',y='FP',title='Under Bonferroni Correction') + 
    opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
        panel.border = theme_blank(),
        panel.background = theme_blank()) + ylim(0.03,0.06)
```

[image]

If I replace shape by group:

[image]

When replacing shape/group by colour:

```
ggplot(data.and.factors.prov,aes(x=Design.Complexity,y=FP,colour=factor(All.interactions))) + 
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal,position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) + 
geom_blank() + 
geom_smooth(method='lm',se=F,formula=y~x,colour='black')  + 
scale_shape_manual(values=c(17,3,16,6,15,4),
                   name='Interactions',
                   labels=c('No interactions','All possible interactions','Randomly picked interactions\nand direct effects')) + 
labs(x='Design.complexity',y='FP',title='Under Bonferroni Correction') + 
opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
    panel.border = theme_blank(),
    panel.background = theme_blank()) + ylim(0.03,0.06)
```

[image]

When using both colour and group

[image]

**Why do I get 3 regressions when I use shape but get only 1 regression when I use colour ?**

**How Can I get 3 colored regressions when using colour and how can I get only 1 regression when I use shape ?**

Comment: I assume, and I'm guessing, that it is because of an implicit call to the `group` aesthetic when using `shape` and no implicit call when using `color`... you can verify by adding `group=...` in your `color` version.

Comment: #Justin I don't really understand your comment. But I added some graphs to my post using group that might confirm or not your hypothesis! I also added the precision that I'd like my regressions to coloured according to the points they model.

Comment: I agree generally with Justin's comment, but I am unable (and unwilling) to assist further because your code isn't reproducible.

Comment: I'll second Joran, please make your questions reproducible... but if you want your regressions colored, stop passing `color='black'` to  `geom_smooth`...

Comment: I'm sorry not having given a reproducible example. While I was trying to make one, I indeed found that your answers were sufficient. Using both group and colour in aes() and of course by removing colour='black' in geom_smooth. If anyone want to put that in an answer I'll accept it. Sorry if it was a not well asked and low level question !

Comment: You can write up an answer yourself and accept it. That's allowed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete colour='black' in geom_smooth() and it will automatically gives you the 3 regressions.

If you want to have 3 black regressiosn you can use both group = factor(All.interactions) and colour=factor(All.interactions) in aes() and keep color = 'black' in geom_smooth()